# Get substrings from field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with information about applications. Each document have field **ver** which holds version of application. Examples:

```
"1.0.0.2" (they are strings)
"2.0.3.10"
"3.1.5.111"
```

First 3 digints is *major* version, and last number is *build* version. I wander, is there any way I can get group by *major* version of application?

**Example**

Input collection:

```
{_id: ..., ver: "1.0.0.1"}, 
{_id: ..., ver: "1.0.0.2"}, 
{_id: ..., ver: "2.2.3.0"}
```

Aggregation result:

```
[ 
 {ver:"1.0.0", count:2},
 {ver:"2.2.3", count:1}
]
```

P.S. I'd prefer solution with Aggregation Framework :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr) operator. Following code will do what you want.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({$group: {_id : {$substr : ["$ver", 0,5]}, count:{"$sum" : 1}}});
```

Response will be as follows :

```
[
  {"_id" : "1.0.0", "count" : 2},
  {"_id" : "2.2.3", "count" : 1}
]
```

Comment: Good idea, and it is faster than regex.